# JQM Custom Select not select dynamically items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using the following code in JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 Page, it show a jqm multiple custom select menu.

```
<select id="myselect"  multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="empty">options title</option>
                <option value="a1">option 1</option>
                <option value="a2">option 2</option>
                <option value="a3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

When pagecontainershow occurs I'm searching code snippet to select/check dinamically the multiple options.
It seems in "Selectmenu Widget Api Reference" there aren't any methods.

The component is very good for my purpose, but I need also to control it by javascript (because I have to save to localstorage the items selected and re-select it again on page loading)

https://jsfiddle.net/2s77oc88/3/

Any suggestion?

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to accomplish could you add your javascript/jQuery and even better a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for a faster answer?

Comment: thank you for you comment.

https://jsfiddle.net/2s77oc88/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it here is one [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2s77oc88/5/)
You can select different options by their value using the [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.
 Like so for example: `$("#myselect").val("a2").change();`
 You have to add the .change() method tho to update the Select Menu.

Comment: thank you for the simple solution, the change() method was the key!!